# IO exception while reading/writing to file

Tags: c#

I am using an XML file to store the values. This XML file can be accessed from multiple methods.

```
Private object lockObject = new object()

Method1
{
   Lock(this.lockObject)
   {
     MyCommonMethod()
   }
}

Timer.ElapseEvent
{
   Lock(this.lockObject)
   {
     MyCommonMethod()
   }
}

MyCommonMethod()
{
  // Read/Write to XML file.
  var element = XElement.Load(path);
  // some operations

   element.save(path)
}
```

This class is used by many other classes and some times it throws System.IO exception, the file is already used by other process , although I have used the lock statement

Please guide.

Comment: Are any other processes using that file?

Comment: This will prevent multiple calls to `MyCommonMethod` from the same object at the same time, but if multiple objects have the same `path` at the same time, then this can fail. Do you ensure that there is only one object for each `path`?

Comment: Does the `//some operations` code do anything that would cause MyCommonMethod to be called again (perhaps indirectly)?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple objects of this class , and they all are calling this methods....Named Mutex is the help for this case??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this to be safe across *multiple* instances of the class, you need to make your private locking variable `static`.

```
private static object lockObject = new object();
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, i will surely try this, one more thing - will it create any issue related to memory management, do i need to dispose it? or any other issue

Comment: @RaoBHavik: No, you aren't using any `IDisposable` objects in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all calls to Lock and try to change your code like this:

```
    private void MyCommonMethod()
    {
        lock (this.lockObject)
        {
            var element = XElement.Load(path);
            // some operations
            element.save(path);
        }
    }
```